# Grabbing revenue from website with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to grab revenue from a website past a login page through cURL. I know this is a sloppy way but I have no choice.

```
<?php
$username = "example";
$password = "example";
$postfields = "email=$username&password=$password";
// Use Curl to return the raw source of a webpage to a variable called 
$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // Get the header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Allow redirection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.domain.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$postfields");

$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); // Closing

if (preg_match("/<th>(.*)<\/th/s", $page, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
?>
```

Essentially I am able to get past login fine and it redirects me to the dashboard of the specific website I am trying to grab revenue from, however when trying to use preg_match it doesn't grab anything, it just prints all HTML for the dashboard.

I am trying to only get "$99.99" within the

```
<th>$99.99</th>
```

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your code this line:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

.. otherwise curl just prints out the result of its session. I'd suggest making your regex non-greedy as well: it's only one `<th>` now, but this part of code might be copy-pasted (as a perfectly working one) into some other program - and will cause troubles then. )

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is greedy, and will likely grab the contents of several `<th>` if there are more than one.  It is usually not a good idea to attempt to parse HTML or XML with regular expressions.  An HTML parser will accomplish this task more effectively. I am partial to [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

To solve the problem at hand though,`[^<]+` will gather all characters up to but not including the next `<`.

```
if (preg_match("/<th>([^<]+)<\/th/s", $page, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Use `preg_match_all()` if you have multiple `<th>` to retrieve, as the above will get only the first one.

Comment: Luckily there is only one <th></th> within the page it is redirecting to. However, after trying your code it still only seems to be printing the entire page's HTML code, not just price. Is the redirect effecting this?

Comment: @Ziygo Post the HTML that contains the `<th>`. The redirect shouldn't be responsible if you are getting the correct markup back, but not correctly parsed.

Comment: It's only returning <table><td><th>$11.13</th></td></table> along with a header/footer. The php code I'm using is returning the entire page.